# How to make docker container to connect to WIFI network in Mac OS

Tags: docker

I've done enough of googling and checking with
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings  https://docs.docker.com/network/
and searching over stackoverflow. But I can't find the working answer.

The container is able to talk to any hosts in the Internet with ping, curl but not in WIFI network.

Thank you for your help.

=======

Edit:

Found the culprit.

I was running VPN client.   I just stopped the VPN client and the docker container is able to connect to other hosts in the LAN/WIFI network.

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit.

I was running VPN client.   I just stopped the VPN client and the docker container is able to connect to other hosts in the LAN/WIFI network.